# php: how to generate with command line?

Tags: php, yii, command-line, content-management-system

I want config a cms (yii)

In docs it is said:

2/ Use command line to generate new app:

- php /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/gxccms/core/cms/cms.php cmsapp /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project1

(generate a new project from gxc-cms)

But I can not do this in Windows.

This is all docs.

> ## GXC-CMS-2
>
> Hello and welcome to the new version of GXC-CMS.
>
> Please follow these steps to getting started: 1/ Check out gxc-cms
>   source code at: https://github.com/nganhtuan63/GXC-CMS-2
>
> For example: I checked out source code at
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/gxccms
>
> 2/ Use command line to generate new app:
>
> - php /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/gxccms/core/cms/cms.php cmsapp /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project1
>
> (generate a new project from gxc-cms)
>
> 3/ Install the app, Go to:
>
> http://localhost/project1/backend/install to install. (The
>   installer will check if .locked file existed in common folder or not
>   before installing).
>
> For more information, please check document at:
>
> https://docs.google.com/document/d/1EBDb7WpepBfwV6LjOfx-UdvcoVxQDSZARx_lZnnfe3E/edit
>
> and visit gxc forum: http://forum.gxccms.com/index.php

Comment: Why can't you do this in Windows?

Comment: When I write code in cmd 
Just cms.php is opens.
That's it.